# Reset reducers state when routing the index page with ngrx

Tags: angularjs, ngrx

I am using ngrx in my angular app.

I want to reset some reducers state when use navigate to index page.

I have `trip` an `user` reducers. When user navigate to 'home/index' page I want to reset `trip` reducer state.

How can I do this with ngrx?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can disaptch an action or listen to router actions if you're using the @ngrx/router-store.

Inside the reducer you can listen to this reducer and return the initial state (or undefined).

```
on(indexPageLoaded, () => initialState)
```